# Найти произведение двух наибольших скоростей

Tags: c++

Я писал ЕГЭ по информатике, сегодня стали известны результаты. Почему-то в C4 мне поставили всего лишь 1 балл из 4, хотя задача наипростейшая. К сожалению, у меня нет точной формулировки задания, поэтому напишу по памяти. Вводится сначала число N (количество частиц), потом N скоростей частиц (по условию от -10000 до 10000). Нужно вывести произведение двух наибольших из скоростей. Причём это нужно сделать эффективно по памяти и вычислениям. Вот мой код (точь-в-точь из моей работы):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N; cin >> N;
    int m[2]={-10000, -10000};
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        int mi=(m[1]<m[0]);
        int v; cin >> v;
        m[mi]=(m[mi]<v)? v: m[mi];
    }
    cout << m[0]*m[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Проверил на компьютере у себя, всё нормально работает. Программа эффективна, потому что не заносит все числа в массив, а считает всё по мере ввода чисел. Если не найдёте ошибку в алгоритме, пойду на апелляцию. То ли я неправильно понял условие задачи (тут вы мне конечно не поможете), то ли проверяющим не понравился смайлик `(m[1]<m[0])`, то ли они не проверили мой дополнительный бланк ответов, на котором была написана вторая половина решения.

### Обновление

У меня тут другие подозрения появились. Возможно, что мой код вообще не проверяли, потому что организаторша в ППЭ неправильно номер дополнительного бланка написала и жирно исправила цифру 7 на 3. Возможно, что компьютер принял эту цифру за 8 и из-за этого проверили только часть задания на первом бланке, где написан алгоритм программы на русском языке. Это подтверждается тем, что в критериях оценки написано, что один балл ставится, если "по приведённому тексту решения ясно, что экзаменуемый понимает, из каких этапов должно состоять решение задачи". Только факт того, что я скачал в Интернете все свои бланки, этому противоречит.

### Обновление 2

Всё, нашёл ошибку (см. мой ответ). Всё прояснилось, на апелляцию не пойду.

northerner

> Алгоритм очень плохой. Реально плохой. Как раз на 1 балл. И да, я эксперт ЕГЭ.

А так лучше?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N; cin >> N;
    int m[2]={-10000, -10000};
    int n[2]={10000, 10000};
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        int mi=(m[1]<m[0]), ni=(n[1]>n[0]);
        int v; cin >> v;
        if(m[mi]<v) m[mi]=v;
        if(n[ni]>v) n[ni]=v;
    }
    cout << max(m[0]*m[1], n[0]*n[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: На первый взгляд, если вход нормальный и N  > 1, то правильно. 

Может быть следовало рассмотреть варианты с N < 2 ?

Comment: Проверяет вероятней всего какаето тетя Таня, которая в программировании вообще нечего не шарит, у нее есть листочек с ответом, там через while написано, буквы не совпадают, бабла для нее в конверте нету, отсюда вместо 4х - 1

Comment: Видимо не совпало с ответами :) 
По-моему всё правильно, если не учитывать лишнего присваивания m[mi] самому себе в случае, если пришло не большее число.

Comment: А условие if ты вообще проверяешь непонятным недя кого способом =) это же ЕГЭ...

Comment: @sercxjo, а вот присвавание после дополнительной проверки **будет менее эффективно**. Прикиньте машинный код.

Comment: N<2 следует считать некорректным, поскольку как выбирать 2 из 1

Comment: >На первый взгляд, если вход нормальный и N > 1, то правильно.
Может быть следовало рассмотреть варианты с N < 2 ?

 Кажется, в условии тоже про это было сказано. По-моему, как раз минимум два элемента должны быть.

>Видимо не совпало с ответами :)

 Какие могут быть ответы, если в программировании результатов - миллионы?

>По-моему всё правильно, если не учитывать лишнего присваивания m[mi] самому себе в случае, если пришло не большее число.

 Обычно в C пишут то же самое через макрос max. Я бы его использовал, но боялся, что он не определён или  будет конфликтовать с std::max.

Comment: Отличный код, создатели ЕГЭ на такое не расчитывали видимо.

Comment: @avp почему будет менее эффективно?

Comment: @sercxjo, если Вы по поводу конкретного кода

    m[mi]=(m[mi]<v)? v: m[mi]; 

вместо 

    if (m[mi]<v) m[mi] = v;

то **Вы правы**, а я погорячился. Вариант с if лучше.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Автор неверно написал в теме условие задачи, необходимо найти максимальное из произведений всех пар скоростей, а не произведение двух наибольших скоростей. В критериях выставления *одного* балла четко написано:

> Предложен лишь частично верный алгоритм решения: в программе ищутся значения только максимальных элементов.

Здесь пошла нездоровая дискуссия о том, что, мол, школьные учителя ничего не понимают в программировании, поэтому работу зарезали. Так вот, я к тому, что *в данном случае* всё совершенно не так, один балл выставлен справедливо.

Comment: >Здесь пошла нездоровая дискуссия о том, что, мол, школьные учителя ничего не понимают в программировании

 Вообще-то, в школе у меня в школе такой учитель и был. В диагностических работах только части A и B с ответами сверял, а C даже не смотрел. Дал спецификацию и сказал проверять самостоятельно. Правда на то, чтобы стать экспертом он и не претендовал.

Comment: Это правда, так бывает. Экспертная комиссия ЕГЭ формируется 50 на 50 из школьных учителей и преподавателей ВУЗов.

Интересно, как ваш учитель поступил с последней тренировочной статградовской работы, где правильные ответы были перемешаны между вариантами.

На вопрос @avp (там кончился лимит комментариев): зависит от контекста, решая задачку на олимпиадном сервере, я бы как-то так и сам написал, в серьезном проекте избегал бы подобного и другим членам команды не рекомендовал бы.

Comment: М... А разьве произведение двух наибольших скоростей не равно максимальному произведению их всех пар скоростей?

Comment: @oleg_ismaylov `-10000 * -10000`

Comment: Скорость - векторная величина. Поэтому не может быть отрицательной.

Comment: @oleg_ismaylov

- Проекции векторов еще никто не отменял.

- Если вы действительно хотите продолжить этот разговор, то скорость как векторная величина не может быть и *положительной*, поскольку в данном контексте имеет смысл только положительность / отрицательность какой-либо `R1` метрики, введенной для векторов.

- И да, если уж говорить о скорости как о векторной величине, то как в контексте данной задачи вы представляете себе **произведение скоростей?**

Comment: я имел ввиду, что скорости - только положительные.

Comment: @oleg_ismaylov Понятненько.

Answer (score 11):

> - Мне кажется, что если бы вы написали бы программу, аналогичную вашей, но не занимаясь [`Code golf'ом`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf), то получили бы `4/4` *(если, конечно, условия типа `N >= 2` действительно фигурируют в задании)*. Потенциально еще можно было проверить `input` на корректность.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    static const int MIN_VALUE = -10000;
    static const int MAX_VALUE = 10000;

    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    assert(n >= 2);

    int firstMaximum = MIN_VALUE;
    int secondMaximum = MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int velocity;
        std::cin >> velocity;
        assert(velocity >= MIN_VALUE &&
               velocity <= MAX_VALUE);

        if (velocity > firstMaximum)
        {
            secondMaximum = firstMaximum;
            firstMaximum = velocity;
        }
        else if (velocity > secondMaximum)
        {
            secondMaximum = velocity;
        }
    }

    std::cout << firstMaximum * secondMaximum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: >но не занимаясь Code golf'ом

 Для меня та конструкция привычна, я ей пользуюсь давно, и не вижу в ней ничего сложного. На то, чтобы её придумать и написать у меня уходит меньше времени, чем написание этих больших if'ов.

Comment: @GLmonster Только вы забываете, что пишете код не для себя, а для *других* людей :)

Comment: Ну что тут сказать. Грамотная, понятная, эффективная, легко модифицируемая ...

Просто образец для разных экзаменов.

Comment: @Котик люто бешено плюсую на счет кода для других. В идеале было чтобы весь код был понятен тому кому его могут передать. Иногда бывает слишком много времени уходит на понимание, и уже что-то добавить свое страшно становится

Comment: >Только вы забываете, что пишете код не для себя, а для других людей :)

 Даже и подумать не мог, что эта конструкция такая сложная, как здесь все считают. Я даже вообще хотел её вместо mi подставить, не заводя переменную, но подумал, что будет менее читабельно. А вообще это как раз в духе ЕГЭ. Там в заданиях части A и B истину обозначают 1, ложь - 0. А тут и есть условие, которое даёт 0 или 1. Логично ведь?

Comment: @GLMonster никто её тут сложной не считает. Только тут у вас 3 строки. А представляете когда такого кода хотя бы 1000 строк. А тех кто проверяет ЕГЭ, мы увы знать не можем (проверял бы кто-то из нас, скорее всего 4/4 получили бы :) )

Comment: upd. Коли выяснилось, что задание было другое соглашусь с оценкой. Тем более появилися эксперт ЕГЭ и разъяснил критерии. У нас я тоже знаю экспертов (преподаватели нашего ВУЗа), вполне адекватные люди.

Answer (score 11):

Кое-что узнал в Интернете. Оказывается, я не учёл того, что произведение двух больших по модулю отрицательных чисел может быть больше, чем положительных, а по условию надо было указать именно наибольшее произведение, а не произведение наибольших чисел.
 Вот блин...

Comment: ну так, это все проясняет:)

Comment: Жаль, столько обсуждали, а программа решает не ту задачку...

Comment: Но не один же балл! В критериях к задаче C4 (правда другой) написано: "Три балла также выставляется, если в эффективной программе, удовлетворяющей критериям выставления 4 баллов, есть одна ошибка, в результате которой программа работает неверно на некоторых наборах нетипичных входных данных".

>Жаль, столько обсуждали, а программа решает не ту задачку...

 А мне-то как жаль... Даже не знаю, идти ли на апелляцию теперь. Ладно, пойду всё равно, наверное.

Comment: теперь осталось доказать, что программа работает "правильно" в большинстве случаев. Проверять правильнее всего на компьютере (что бы у проверяющих не было шансов давить утверждением "а мне не понятно!").
При правильном подходе и подборе входных данных можно и 4 бала получить:)

Comment: по-моему это стоит указать в тексте вопроса

Comment: @GLmonster, на апелляцию все равно идите, вдруг в Интернете Вы нашли другую задачу ?

Но, если ту, то для правильного решения надо было искать отдельно 2 максимума и 2 минимума. Сможете доказать, что это именно одна ошибка для нетипичных данных ?

Comment: >по-моему это стоит указать в тексте вопроса

 Что именно указать?

>вдруг в Интернете Вы нашли другую задачу ?

 Как раз другую и нашёл. В той надо минимальное произведение найти. Просто по аналогии вспомнил, что у меня тоже нужно найти наибольшее произведение, а не произведение наибольших чисел.

>Сможете доказать, что это именно одна ошибка для нетипичных данных ?

 В смысле, доказать отсутствие других ошибок? Других вроде нет.

Comment: @GLmonster, ваш ответ

Comment: Нет, здесь очевидно один балл. Один в один по критериям. Я на самом деле сочувствую автору, потому что в этом году каждый первичный балл C4 стоит трёх баллов в стобалльной шкале, следовательно, теряя 3 первичных балла теряешь сразу 9 - и это как-то слишком жестко, но, увы, ничего не попишешь.

Comment: >Нет, здесь очевидно один балл. Один в один по критериям.

 А где можно посмотреть на критерии? А то я смотрел на критерии из своей диагностической работы с другой задачей, думал, что они похожи.

>Я на самом деле сочувствую автору

 Да, дорого мне стоила моя невнимательность и уверенность. Не надо было на полчаса раньше с экзамена уходить... Ну ладно, на поступление в вуз это не повлияет, моих 88 баллов для этого вполне хватит. Просто, я не могу успокоиться, пока не узнаю, в чём я не прав или не докажу свою правоту.

Comment: > А где можно посмотреть на критерии?

Официально нигде. Там на этом документе так и написано: "копирование не допускается". Можете все равно сходить на апелляцию - маловероятно, что поднимут (хотя и такое бывает, эксперт в конфликтной комиссии - *тоже человек*), но должны обосновать оценку и не исключено, что покажут критерии.

> Ну ладно, на поступление в вуз это не повлияет

Вот это самое главное. В остальном - это просто экзамен, нет смысла зацикливаться, лучше сосредоточиться на остальных экзаменах (говорят, математика была сложная). Успехов!

Answer (score 10):

[@Котик](/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), mi=(m[1]<m[0]) это правильно (*по хакерски*).

Использование граничных значений для алгоритма - вполне в духе, скажем, Д. Кнута.

А вот к N < 2 действительно можно придраться. Но если не придираться, то IMHO super. Я бы пошел на апелляцию.

Comment: Не думаю, что кому-то нужно знаменитое *"хакерство"*, `KR-like` способ закодировать что-то и т.д. на ЕГЭ. А вот написать код, который поймет тетя Таня и дядя Вася - это тоже искусство. Разумеется, на правах `IMHO`.

Answer (score 8):

вполне вероятно, что во время написания ЕГЭ, вы упустили какую-то важную деталь, которую сочли незначительной. а так как вы воспроизвели задачу по памяти, вероятность того что вы упустили ее при репродукции еще выше...

любые рассмотрения кода не имеют смысла пока не будет представлено точное ТЗ

Comment: >вполне вероятно, что во время написания ЕГЭ, вы упустили какую-то важную деталь, которую сочли незначительной

 Я допускаю, что я мог неправильно понять условие, но его у меня нет. Поэтому я пытаюсь исключить по крайней мере всё остальное. Но исходный код точно такой же, я его переписал со скана листа работы.

>любые рассмотрения кода не имеют смысла пока не будет представлено точное ТЗ

 К сожалению, не будет. Ладно, на апелляции узнаю.

Comment: @GLmonster, попробуйте поискать в нете схожие задания - говорят, некоторые варианты задач можно найти, может и Ваша среди них встретится

Answer (score 7):

Алгоритм оч. хороший. Реально хороший. Особенно нравится выражение `mi=(m[1]<m[0])` - это заслуживает отдельной похвалы за кодирование полузабытом штиле Кернигана-Ритчи. Надо идти на апелляцию.

**Update**

*@Northener писал:*

> Автор неверно написал в теме условие
> задачи, необходимо найти максимальное
> из произведений всех пар скоростей, а
> не произведение двух наибольших
> скоростей.

Это конечно меняет все. В этом случае алгоритм работает неверно, увы. Но автор все равно молодец - я получил эстетическое удовольствие от предложенного алгоритма.

Comment: >Надо идти на апелляцию.

 Завтра пойду писать заявление.

Comment: > Алгоритм оч. хороший. Реально хороший.

Алгоритм очень плохой. Реальной плохой. Как раз на 1 балл. И да, я эксперт ЕГЭ.

Comment: @northerner, объясните подробно. 

А то Вы оцениваете учеников, а мы им работу потом даем. Интересно несовпадение критериев.

Comment: @northerner, с тем, что программа не ту задачу решает все ясно (вопросов нет). Вопрос об 

    Алгоритм очень плохой. Реально плохой


для задачи, *как ее автор описал*.

Comment: @northerner А как при выставлении общего балла относятся к вещам типа `mi=(m[1]<m[0])`?

Comment: @Котик\_хочет\_кушать, используемые конструкции и стиль не играют роли. Хорошо это или плохо - другой вопрос, факт, что критерии явным образом определяют правила игры так.

Другое дело - человеческий фактор. Эксперт может ошибиться. Правда для этого каждую работу и проверяют двое отдельно, при разнице в один балл ставится большая оценка, при большей разнице включается третий эксперт, и предусмотрена апелляция. Но все же рекомендую писать по-человечески - ниже вероятность срезать верное решение.

Comment: @Spectre, даже если не по абсолютному значению, то у 2-х самых отрицательных произведение может оказаться максимальным.

Comment: Два года назад я участвовал в конфликтной комиссии и повышал балл, когда например, паренек использовал в качестве проверки на нечетность выражение (x & 1), а оба эксперта зарезали.

Тем более, в C4 ЕГЭ допускается *любой* язык высокого уровня, но то есть вообще любой. В этом году кроме стандартных Pascal, C, C++ мне попадался только Python, но год на год не приходится - в прошлом году был знатный зоопарк. PHP, например, попадался. Эксперт может быть не знаком с языком, но он обязан проверить.

Comment: @avp, да, вы абсолютно правы

@northerner, наверно, из ваших комментов стоит сделать ответ, т.к. он будет наиболее верным

Comment: @northerner, и все таки, алгоритм плохой ?

Comment: > А то Вы оцениваете учеников, а мы им работу потом даем.

Я и тем, и другим занимаюсь. Критерии, конечно, разные, потому что цели разные и, соответственно, диагностируемый набор компетенций.

Comment: >Тем более, в C4 ЕГЭ допускается любой язык высокого уровня, но то есть вообще любой. Эксперт может быть не знаком с языком, но он обязан проверить.

 Думал на D написать сначала, но передумал. Слишком уж быстро язык меняется и наловить кучу ошибок очень легко.

Angry Bird, не заметил, удалил.

Comment: >В этом случае алгоритм работает неверно, увы. Но автор все равно молодец - я получил эстетическое удовольствие от предложенного алгоритма.

 Я его исправил в обновлении вопроса 2. Теперь можешь получать эстетическое удовольствие от исправленного. Больше он ни на что не годится, потому что баллы не поменяет.

Answer (score 5):

Что то я не видел, что бы кто то писал о отрицательных скоростях. Если оставить в стороне то, что нужен ещё вектор направления, то отрицательная скорость - это просто движения в противоположную сторону. В исходном коде бы исправил начальные значения на `int m[2]={0, 0};` и при вводе скорость брал бы по модулю.

Но вот выражение `mi=(m[1]<m[0])` на ЕГЭ я бы не писал. При собеседовании - можно (а иногда даже нужно), на ЕГЭ - не стоит.

Comment: выражение mi=(m[1]<m[0]) должно вернуть 0 если m[0]>=m[1] и 1 в противном случае? Я вот точно не помню, но в сях по описанию вроде значение 0 - это фалсе, отличное от нуля - труе. И почему будет такая уверенность что тру компилятор преобразует в 1? может так же преобразовать в m[0]-m[1]? Или я что то путаю?

Comment: а я не утверждаю, что оно возвратит только 0 или 1. В стандарте я такого утверждения не нашел. Поэтому на ЕГЭ и не стоит так делать. А вот на собеседовании, когда можем выбирать компилятор, можно и использовать, там объяснять проще будет.

Comment: кстати, а вроде не было сказано что скорости целые

Comment: >Что то я не видел, что бы кто то писал о отрицательных скоростях. Если оставить в стороне то, что нужен ещё вектор направления, то отрицательная скорость - это просто движения в противоположную сторону.

 Отрицательные скорости были по условию. Это я точно помню.

>Но вот выражение mi=(m[1]<m[0]) на ЕГЭ я бы не писал.

 А как ещё, через if'ы целых две строчки писать? Или `(m[1]<[m[0])? 1: 0`?

Comment: Классическая проблема - либо сразу пишем три строки и получаем хороший бал, либо пишем одну, потом ходим, доказываем. Как по мне - первое значительно эффективно. Так что топикстартер решил задачу не оптимально.
выражение `(m[1]<[m[0])? 1: 0` - более красивое.

Но в целом, задача написана на с, а не на с++.

Comment: я нашел такие входные данные, когда код не решает поставленную задачу. например, если все входные данные равны
алгоритм не работает:) проверьте при входных данных 

    3
    -9999
    9999
    0

я ожидаю в ответе не 0.

Comment: @KoVadim, я имел в виду что такие выражение можно писать зная чётко что за компилятор, платформа и т.д. Это как раз согласие с вашим утверждением о запрете.

Comment: @KoVadim, во чем-то Вы правы, но если смотреть глубже, то мне вообще непонятен смысл перемножения скоростей *разных* объектов.

Comment: >И почему будет такая уверенность что тру компилятор преобразует в 1?

 Всю жизнь так вроде было. На gamedev'е была такая тема, где функцию получения знака числа так написали, как у меня ниже. Даже никто не усомнился в том, что это стандартное поведение, хотя там любят это обсуждать.

>и при вводе скорость брал бы по модулю.

 Например, используя смайлик в моём стиле: v*((v>0)-(v<0)).

>кстати, а вроде не было сказано что скорости целые

 В ЕГЭ все числа целые во всех задачах.

Comment: @GLmonster - принципиального отличия между if и mi = (m[1]<[m[0]) нету, и там и там скорее всего сгенерируется код который вычтет одно число из другого и проверит флаги, только второй вариант сильно зависит от аппаратной части и версии и настроек компилятора, не предвнося понимания кода, тогда как вариант с if даст более простой для понимания код, без потери качества генерируемого выполняемого кода.

Comment: >я ожидаю в ответе не 0.

 По условию было перемножение именно максимальных значений, а 0 и 9999 и есть максимальные.

>мне вообще непонятен смысл перемножения скоростей разных объектов.

 В условии объяснялось, что это нужно для того, чтобы дать название, характеризующее отдельные эксперименты. Ну вообще всё это словесная мишура, а что именно надо делать должно было быть написано чётко, чтобы не нужно было догадываться.

Comment: @KoVadim,

    я нашел такие входные данные, когда код не решает поставленную задачу

Проверил на Вашем примере, а также, когда все числа равны - нет **все работает** (программа правильная).

Comment: я считаю, что при исходных данных

    3
    -9999
    9999
    0
правильный ответ должен быть 99980001 ( = 9999*9999).

И ещё. Программа не проверяет, что введенное N - отрицательное либо 0. Как по мне - это большой минус.

Comment: @KoVadim Нулевая скорость больше, чем отрицательная. Если, конечно, в задаче не фигурировал модуль.

Comment: >Программа не проверяет, что введенное N - отрицательное либо 0. Как по мне - это большой минус.

 В реальных программах - да. Но в условии было чётко сказано, что как минимум будет 2 элемента. Тем более, что не понятно, что выводить при N<1.

>Если, конечно, в задаче не фигурировал модуль.

 Вроде не фигурировал.

Comment: В оригинальном условии задачи, разумеется, было сказано, что числа целые:

> На вход программе в первой строке подается количество частиц N. В каждой из последующих строк записано одно целое число со знаком, по абсолютной величине не превышающее 10000.

Там же было сказано, что перемножать нужно скорости различных частиц.

Answer (score 5):

Не разделяю восторгов по поводу хакерски-керниганского кода.

```
int mi=(m[1]<m[0])
```

Подумайте, какой тип данных возвращает `rvalue` и какой тип вы объявляете для `lvalue`, учитывая, что речь идёт о **крестах**, а не о труси бородатых времен Ритчи.

> Какие могут быть ответы, если в программировании результатов - миллионы?

О **правильных** (проверенных вручную!) ответах на определенный тестовый набор данных. Знаете, как работают юнит-тесты?

В целом, как уже отметили предыдущие ораторы, не помня точного задания бессмысленно оценивать правильность реализации, и остается только оценивать стиль, который, как уже тоже отметили, возможно, хорош для codegolf'а, но не для прочтения человеком, тем более настроенным критически и от которого зависит оценка работы.

Comment: >Подумайте, какой тип данных возвращает rvalue и какой тип вы объявляете для lvalue

 Судя по всему, bool, который конвертируется в int.

>Далее, кстати, у вас потенциальный выход за пределы массива.

 true - 1, false - 0. Разве может быть по-другому?

>речь идёт о крестах, а не о труси бородатых времен Ритчи.

 А как же обратная совместимость? Разве даже в таких мелочах не сохраняется обратная совместимость?

Comment: @karmadro4, в g++ код работает.

Самое главное, автор продемонстрировал нетривиальный подход к поиску 2-х максимальных элементов, т.е. творческое мышление, а также способность писать компактный код в условиях дефицита времени (экзамен).

@GLmonster, очень интересно, а сколько программок надо было написать и за какое время ?

--

В данных условиях - это 5+.

Другой вопрос, если код решает не ту задачу. Тогда из автоматизированных тестов пройдет только компиляция и исполнение с кодом возврата 0.

Comment: @GLmonster Программировать на `C++`, исходя из обратной совместимости с `C` - это **самое страшное,** что только можно предпринять. Отсюда и рождаются грабли с миллионами `new / delete` в коде, вещи типа `operator bool`, отсюда растут ноги у использования `int` для хранения значения булевского выражения и `C-style` касты, ломающие использование `vfptr` и `vcbl`. Если уж взялись писать на `C++`, то используйте `bool` для хранения булевского значения.

Comment: @GLmonster,

> Судя по всему, bool, 

Совершенно верно, `bool`. Но вы этог тип не использовали, а прибегли к инту a-la труси.

> true - 1, false - 0. Разве может быть по-другому?

Неправильно, `const bool false = 0; const bool true = !false;`, остальное - implementation specific.

А про обратную совместимость уже Котик хорошо сказал.

@avp, странная у вас логика. Если 

> способность писать компактный код в условиях дефицита времени
> это 5+

то тогда сколько же баллов за развернутый код? ;-) Кстати, весьма символично, что компактность нарушается когда дело доходит до тернистого оператора :-)

Comment: >Программировать на C++ в духе C - это самое страшное, что только можно предпринять, поскольку C++ - это совершенно другой язык.

 Я даже и не подозревал, что программирую в духе C. Я с самого начала начинал изучать C++.

>Если уж взялись писать на C++, то используйте bool для хранения булевского значения.

 Дело не в этом (см. ниже).

>Совершенно верно, bool. Но вы этог тип не использовали, а прибегли к инту a-la труси.

 Потому что для типа индекса массива логичнее использовать int. bool бы тоже сработал, но int читабельнее.

Comment: >Неправильно, const bool false = 0; const bool true = !false;, остальное - implementation specific.

 Доказательство?

>очень интересно, а сколько программок надо было написать и за какое время ?

 В части A 13 заданий с выбором варианта ответа, в B - 15 с кратким ответом. Экспертами проверяется только часть C. C1 - поиск ошибки в программе и указание способа исправления. C2 - написание небольшого фрагмента программы. Обычно 4-5 строк: пройтись по массиву и что-то сделать с его элементами. C3 - задача, не связанная с программированием. C4 вы сами видели. На всё даётся 4 часа.

Comment: @GLmonster

- Я ничего не сказал конкретно про вас, тем более без реальных фрагментов кода вряд ли можно сказать, как вы программируете. Тем не менее, я обратил свое внимание на то, что сохранять значение булевского типа в переменной типа `int`, имея в распоряжении тип `bool` - это жесткий `ANSI-C` стайл.

- Утверждения о читабельности, как мы выяснили в этом треде, настолько спорны и недоказуемы, что вряд ли можно применять их как аргумент.

Comment: @GLmonster

- Утверждение про `implementation-specific bool,` судя по всему, некорректно, либо я неправильно интерпретирую пункт [`4.7 - Integral Conversions`][1] стандарта `C++`.

> If the source type is bool, the value false is converted to zero and the value true **is converted to one.**

[1]: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf#page=98

Comment: @GLmonster, хм, это я, пожалуй, попутал с _Bool из сей недавнего разлива. Таким образом с потенциальным выходом за пределы я был неправ.

Comment: >If the source type is bool, the value false is converted to zero and the value true is converted to one.

 Ну вот, то что я утверждал и подтвердилось: трюк от реализации не зависит.

>сохранять значение булевского типа в переменной типа int, имея в распоряжении тип bool - это жесткий ANSI-C стайл.

 Если бы я увидел код

    int condition=(x<0);
    if(condition) ...;

то я бы тоже негодовал и заменил бы на bool, но когда это значение используется как индекс массива, логичнее использовать int.

Comment: Хмм... Однако, тенденция! Я слоупочу, а Котик перехватывает все мои реплики и даже поправляет меня если ошибусь :-)

Насчет типа индекса массива всё неоднозначно, к примеру в Паскале логический тип принадлежит множеству порядковых типов и запись `array[Boolean] of ...` была бы кошерной, а в крестах из-за слабой типизации всё превращается в неявную кашу.

Comment: @karmadro4 Я вообще недавно был шокирован тем, что у меня вот [эта вот страница][1] попала в топ16 вкладок хрома :)

[1]: http://hashcode.ru/users/6679/karmadro4/recent/